# Read or modify Sonarqube PLSQL plugin inbuilt rules

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonar-runner, sonarlint, sonarqube5.1

I have used SonarQubes PLSQL plugin rules , example rule for
**Primary key** required during table creation.

is there a way I can read the XPATH query written for creating this rule.
or read XPATH query for any other inbuilt rule of the PLSQL plugin.

**I need to create a custom rule using XPATH which is similar to primary key rule.**

thanks,

Answer (score 0):

No, that's not possible: the built-in rules are not written using XPath.